# Accessing fragment method from async task

Tags: android

First off, is this a good practice, accessing a fragment's method from an asynchronous task?

I have an async task which generates a list of LatLng which is use in my fragment to draw a polyline. However, if i try to use a getter method to get the list.

```
    public List<LatLng> getList() {
    return this.list;
}
```

I get `nullpointerexceptions` so i have to perform this inside the fragment,

```
while(list == null) { // FIXME delay because of this 
    list = getRoute.getList();
}
```

Which defeats the purpose of having a background task.

Is there a way I can call the method from within the async task's post execute method?

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(OTPResponseUI otpResponse) {
            Fragment.fragmentsMethod(getList());
            mDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

This way i can correctly show the process dialog and not leave the user hanging while it loads the list.

**UPDATE**
I tried invoking a callback like [this](http://blog.evoxmusic.fr/content/how-implement-callback-asynctask) but the callback function in my fragment is not executed.

**UPDATE2**
Ok i just passed the fragment instance to the async task to be able to call the fragment method. As per your advice:

> Create the list object in your custom AsyncTask class, and then return it back to the Fragment in the postExecute() method. You can do this by directly calling a method on the Fragment instance (that you'll get either via the constructor. It works, thanks!

Comment: Can you just pass your `Fragment` instance into the constructor of the `AsyncTask`? Also, is your `AsyncTask` getting the list in order to fill it? Why not just return a filled list that is instantiated within your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @unluddite for the first one, how do i do that? And yes, the `AsyncTask` is just used to fill it up. I don't think I could return a filled list in an `AsyncTask`, could i? That's why i thought of calling a method. It worked previously using activities, `((ActivityName) mContext).method(getList());`, i just want to do it using fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

Define your own custom `AsyncTask` class and pass the `List` that you want filled into either its constructor:

```java
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private List<LatLng> mTheList;

    public MyAsyncTask(List<LatLng> theList) {
        mTheList = theList;
    }

    // fill the list in doInBackground()

    ...
}

// in your fragment

MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(theList);
task.execute();
```

**OR** you can pass it as a parameter to the `execute()` method:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<LatLng>,Void,Void> {
    public Void doInBackgroun(List<LatLng>...args {
        List<LatLng> theList = args[0];
        // fill the list
    }
}
```

Note that you can also pass the `Fragment` instance to the `execute()` method in the same way and then call the `getList()` method on that instance (I don't like this option).

A better option would be:

Create the list object in your custom `AsyncTask` class, and then return it back to the `Fragment` in the `postExecute()` method. You can do this by directly calling a method on the `Fragment` instance (that you'll get either via the constructor or as an argument to the `execute()` method) that accepts the list as a parameter. But, another (cleaner) way is to define an interface within your custom `AsyncTask` class for a callback method that accepts the filled list as an argument. Then your `Fragment` can implement this callback interface, add itself to the task as a "listener", and have the task call that inteface method, passing the filled list as an agrument inside the task's `postExecute()` method.

Comment: I pass in a class that includes a list of polyline options and a list of marker options.  In the result of the class I call a method to add the polyline options and the markers to the map

Comment: @unluddite, i tried your first two options but still cannot get any items in the list before the next activity the needs the list is called. Do you mind if you place a sample code of how to implement the last option you suggested?

Comment: Based on your response, it doesn't sound like the last option would help you any. The options are all achieving the same result--fill a list in an `AsyncTask` and deliver the result back to the caller--but just use different style/design. I think you need to elaborate more on what you mean by: _cannot get any items in the list before the next activity the needs the list is called_. If you need to wait for the `AsyncTask` result, then don't start the next activity until `onPostExecute()` runs.